# NginX as reverse proxy with v 1.10.3

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am a network & system administrator.
I need to configure `NginX` as a reverse proxy 
I have seen many tutorials, but did not find the exact answer.

I have 3 servers - Each one has an app running (with `apache`). Every app is accessible through the IP address and a specified port of the server.

I need a reverse proxy server with `NginX` that leta me access these 3 servers without specifying the IP address and the port. In other words the IP address and the port are hidden.

Example app : xxx.xx.x.xx:9292/app with reverse proxy, accessing it would be done like this: server1.app.org

I already have `NginX` installed with version 1.10.3 but it is missing sites-enabled and sites-available folders, which confused me little!

In some tutorials, they don't use these folders, they just use `files.conf` in `conf.d`

I am wondering if the 3 servers need `NginX` to be installed in to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered you on your previous question! There is no need to delete that question and answer the same thing in a new question that is pretty much like the old one!

**UPDATE:**

```
http {
    upstream websites {
        server 172.20.0.31:9292;
        server 172.20.0.11:9191;
        server 172.20.0.222:9393;
    }

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://websites;
        }
    }
}
```

The config above applies the round-robin principle for load balacing the requests to all your servers.

Of course your website has to load when you access it in the browser like http://172.20.0.31:9292.

If not, then either you configure a vhost for that or you just use local dns names (you can add on your nginx server **/etc/hosts** file names for your servers and point them to the servers' ip addresses)

Comment: in you answer you gave me some informations to clearify the way NginX works and thank you so very much for that.
but what i'm stuck with.. is the config itself.
now i have made another CentOS 7 server with fresh NginX installed (without sites-available and sites-enabled and the default.conf )

how can i fullfill the need in the question ?
other words..
what is the ideal config to make NginX work like i asked ?

thank you.. again.

Comment: Please provide your actual setup like ip address for your nginx server and then ip addresses for the servers behind...

Comment: `Nginx` 1.10.3 on Centos 7 ip : `172.20.0.120`
**server 1**  running **app 1** ip : **172.20.0.31** port **9292**
 **server 2**  running **app 1** ip : **172.20.0.11** port **9191**
  **server 3**  running **app 1** ip : **172.20.0.222** port **9393**

Comment: `the 3 servers run **3 different apps** respectively`

does the config you already post match to task ?!

or the config be like this :

`http {
    upstream website1 {
        server 172.20.0.31:9292;
    }

http {
    upstream website2 {
        server 172.20.0.11:9191;
    }

http {
    upstream website3 {
        server 172.20.0.222:9393;
    }

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://website1;
            proxy_pass http://website2;
            proxy_pass http://website3;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: The config makes no difference on what app is running on each server. It is supposed that when you access 172.20.0.31:9292 then you go directly to that app or whatever it is. I think you should read nginx documentation first, make an idea on how nginx can be used as a load balancer and reverse proxy!

Comment: ok.. i read the documentation and i konw load balacing and reverse proxy.
  i just wanted to know if NginX cand do what i asked.. and if it can how (the config) ?


so i copied the config you gave me..    it doesn't work !

when i restart it gives me this :
`[root@proxy x-user]# service nginx restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  nginx.service
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
`